# mysql combined statement with an individual test for each field

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update, case

Can these update statements be combined into one  update statement or looped through to assemble the desired statement? The goal is to only update fields that are empty or null. P_Id is AI. @Existing_P_Id = '1'(Sorry corrected MI)

```
UPDATE participant 
SET First_Name = @existing_First_Name 
WHERE P_Id = @existing_P_Id AND First_Name = '';
    
UPDATE participant 
SET MI = @existing_MI 
WHERE P_Id = @existing_P_Id AND MI = '';
    
UPDATE participant 
SET Last_Name = @existing_Last_Name 
WHERE P_Id = @existing_P_Id AND Last_Name = '';
```

Comment: As always more then one way to skin the cat. Thank you for all the help it gives me a good perspective on combining the statements. Seems all three ways are viable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your MI column should be set to a variable `@existing_MI`

```
UPDATE participant
SET First_Name = IFNULL(NULLIF(First_Name,''), @existing_First_Name),
    MI         = IFNULL(NULLIF(MI,''),         @existing_MI),
    Last_Name  = IFNULL(NULLIF(Last_Name,''),  @existing_Last_Name)
WHERE P_Id = @existing_P_Id;
```

Reference:

- [IFNULL()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull) returns either its first argument or second argument, the first that is not NULL.
- [NULLIF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_nullif) returns NULL if its first argument is equal to its second argument, otherwise it returns the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` in the `WHERE` clause and conditional expressions in the `SET` clause:

```
UPDATE participant 
SET 
    First_Name = CASE WHEN First_Name = '' THEN @existing_First_Name ELSE First_Name END,
    MI         = CASE WHEN MI         = '' THEN @existing_MI         ELSE MI         END,
    Last_Name  = CASE WHEN Last_Name  = '' THEN @existing_Last_Name  ELSE Last_Name  END
WHERE 
    P_Id = @existing_P_Id 
    AND '' IN (First_Name, MI, Last_Name)
```

Comment: Guess I would just add that Case can only be used in a stored procedure, or a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do this.

I guess you have the values you want to use for the conditional updates in your `@existing_whatever` session variables.  I don't understand what you want for `MI`, so I left that out of my answer.

Here's your update code (be  sure to test this).

```
UPDATE participant SET
  first_name = IF(first_name IS NULL OR LENGTH(first_name) = 0, 
                  @existing_First_Name, last_name),
  last_name = IF(last_name IS NULL OR LENGTH(last_name) = 0,
                   @existing_Last_Name, last_name)
WHERE P_Id = @existing_P_Id
```

The `IF()` functions do the conditional updating, using either the `@existing_...` value or the value of the column already in the table.

You can add this to the end of your UPDATE to avoid touching the row at all if it doesn't need any changes.

```
AND (first_name IS NULL OR LENGTH(first_name) = 0  OR
     last_name IS NULL OR LENGTH(last_name) = 0)
```